# Constructing JSON string from sys_refcursor using list_agg

Tags: arrays, json, sys-refcursor

Can any one tell me how to construct json from sys_refcusrosr using list_agg in a stored procedure?I am getting error result of "string concatenation is too long" when i do so?

Create or replace procedure employee( 
               p_employee_num IN NUMBER, 
               p_next_level   IN NUMBER,
               p_record_out   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

as
BEGIN 
OPEN p_record_out  for
WITH  employee_details 
         as     ( Select '{' ||'"EMPLOYEE PARENT NAME"'
                 || employee_parent_level
                     || '",'
                             || '"EMPLOYEE CHILD Name"'
                 || employee_child_level
                             || '} ,'
                           json 
          from 
          employee
          start with employee_child_level = p_employee_num 
                  connect by prior employee_child_level = employee_parent_level
          and level < (1 +p_next_level)
                  order by level)
    select '{"company" : ['
                ||( select listagg( json, ',')
                        within group (order by 1)
                    from   employee_details
                    )
                ||']}'
            from   dual;
end employee;

Comment: declare 
   p_record   sys_refcursor;
   v_hierarchy varchar2(10000);
Begin
 employee(p_employee_num =>12345,
          p_next_level   => 1,
   p_record_out   => p_record   
  );
Loop 
fetch  p_record   into v_hierarchy;
exit when p_record%notfound;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_hierarchy);
END LOOP;
CLOSE p_record;
END;

Comment: Used above to execute the procedure but getting error string concatenation is too long